# Problem in functions.php file

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to include all my css and JS files of a theme using `functions.php`. Following is what I have done so far:

```
 <?php

    function blogroom() {

        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('loaders',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('iconsmind',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/iconsmind/iconsmind.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('hamburgers',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-css',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css');
        wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        wp_register_script( 'imageloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array( 'bootstrap-js' ) );
        wp_register_script( 'tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js', array('imageloaded') );
        wp_register_script( 'scroll-to-plugin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js', array('tweenmax') );
        wp_register_script( 'customToEase', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/CustomEase.min.js', array('scroll-to-plugin') );
        wp_register_script( 'configJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/config.js', array('customToEase') );
        wp_register_script( 'zanimation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/zanimation.js', array('configJs') );
        wp_register_script( 'corejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/core.js', array('zanimation') );
        wp_register_script( 'mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('corejs') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mainjs' );    
     }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blogroom' );


?>
```

Here, this only loads my CSS file and not my js files. Not a single javascript file is loaded. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is there wp_head and wp_footer in header and footer? Why are you creating such strange dependencies for these scripts? I really don't believe that imageloaded depends on bootstrap-js...

Comment: I did it so that it will load up in sequence. I know its a bad practice but I  just want to test out my first theme for WordPress.

Comment: Yes, I have added wp_head()

Comment: And wp_footer? You register these scripts to be loaded in footer, so if there is no wp_footer in there, they won't load... And if you know it's a bad practice and it makes no sense at all, then why do it? Why not define proper dependencies?

Comment: you just registered your script you need to enqueue those scripts again as `wp_enqueue_script( 'mainjs' ); wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs' ); wp_enqueue_script( 'imageloaded' );` and so on. OR simply change `wp_register_script` to `wp_enqueue_script`.

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace **[wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)** to **[wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)**

wp_register_script is only register script not Enqueue after Enqueue is load.

Comment: That isn't correct. It's true - `wp_register_script` does not enque it, but... if the script is registered and it is listed as dependency for other enqueued script it will get enqueued also .That's why you don't have to enqueue 'jquery' manually and only add it as dependency for your script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue the scripts, it would be registered automatically when you enqueue, 
you can replace the snippet by following,

```
<?php   
function blogroom() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('loaders',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('iconsmind',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/iconsmind/iconsmind.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('hamburgers',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-css',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-style',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'imageloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array( 'bootstrap-js' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js', array('imageloaded') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll-to-plugin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/gsap/src/minified/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js', array('tweenmax') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customToEase', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/lib/CustomEase.min.js', array('scroll-to-plugin') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'configJs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/config.js', array('customToEase') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'zanimation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/zanimation.js', array('configJs') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'corejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/core.js', array('zanimation') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('corejs') );
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blogroom' );
```

Comment: You can, yes. You don't need to... You can list registered scripts as dependencies and they will get enqueued automatically.